# "Add to favourites" button to change class and innerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, button

I need to make an "Add to favs" button that would toggle between "Add" and "Added" states. The trick is that when in "Added" state, I want it to have a hover behaviour like all red and saying "Remove from favs". BUT when you click the button for the 1st time and it changes to "Added", I don't want the 'remove' style turn on immediately.

My solution is to create 2 classes: `.isChecked` and `.isJustPressed`.  The first is used to determine the button actual state and the second is used to apply the "remove from favs" hover styling only after the *mouseleave* event.
These classes are handled by jQuery. I am quite new to the language, so I've come up with such working solution (see below). The CSS is simplified. Well the reason I posted this is that I feel there must be a more elegant way to solve this. And besides, I don't like my jQuery code, so I'd appreciate any comments there also

```js
$('.fav_btn').click(function(event) {
    $(this).addClass('isJustPressed');
    
    $(this).toggleClass('isChecked');
    $(this).html(function() {
        return $('.fav_btn').hasClass('isChecked') ? 'Added' : 'Add  to favourites';
    });
});

$('.fav_btn').on('mouseleave', function(event) {
    if ( $(this).hasClass('isChecked')){ 
        $('.fav_btn').removeClass('isJustPressed');
    }
});


$('.fav_btn').hover(
        function() {
            if ($('.fav_btn').hasClass('isChecked') && !$('.fav_btn').hasClass('isJustPressed')){
                    $('.fav_btn').html('Remove from favourites');
            }},
        function(){
            if ($('.fav_btn').hasClass('isChecked') && !$('.fav_btn').hasClass('isJustPressed')){            
            $('.fav_btn').html('Added');
            }});
```

```css
.fav_btn {
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: lightblue;
}
.fav_btn:hover{
        background-color: blue;
        color: #fff;
}

.fav_btn.fav_btn.isChecked.isJustPressed:hover{
        background-color: blue;
        color: #fff;
}

.fav_btn.isChecked {
        background-color: #fff;
}
.fav_btn.isChecked:hover{
            background: pink;
            color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
 <div class="fav_btn">Add to fav</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for but, I rewrote your solution with more method chaining, and abstraction:

HTML:

```
<div class="fav_btn">Add To Favs</div>
```

JS:

```
//Moved btn text into variable so it can be changed more easily
var btn_text = {
    default: "Add To Favs",
    added: "Selection Added",
    remove: "Remove Selection"
}


$('.fav_btn')
//set initial text and classes
.removeClass('remove added')
.html(btn_text.default)
//The click toggles the 'default' and 'added' states
.on('click', function(e) {

    //Toogle the 'added' class
    $(this).toggleClass('added');

    //Swap the text
    if ($(this).is('.added')) {
        $(this).html(btn_text.added);
    } else {
        $(this)
            .removeClass('remove added')
            .html(btn_text.default)
    }
})
.on('mouseover', function(){
    //If it has the 'added' class...add the 'remove' text 
    if ($(this).is('.added')) {
        $(this)
        .addClass('remove')
        .html(btn_text.remove)
        .on('mouseout', function() {

            //Get rid of the 'remove' class
            $(this).removeClass('remove');

            //Swap out the 'remove' text
            if ($(this).is('.added')) {
                $(this).html(btn_text.added);
            } else {
                $(this).html(btn_text.default);
            }  
        });
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
.fav_btn {
    padding: 5px;
    background-color:blue;
    color: white;
}
.fav_btn:hover {
    background-color: lightblue;
}
.fav_btn.remove:hover {
    background-color: pink;
}
```